# Separating Integers from characters

Tags: vb.net

I have this on my list view 7200 Seconds
Now, when saving data to the database i want to save only 7200
How can i remove the Seconds and save only 7200?

```
        cn.BeginTrans()
        cn.Execute("UPDATE tb_user_account SET st_time_per_day='" & txttpd.text & "' WHERE st_acc_number='" & ListViewAccounts.CheckedItems(I).text & "'")
        cn.CommitTrans()
```

This is the saving code above
txttpd.text is a label containing the string "7200 Seconds"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you specify in your example, the String starts always with the number then you just could Split it:

```
    Dim str As String = "7200 Seconds Now"
    Dim num As Integer = CInt(str.Split.First)
```

Otherwise, If maybe the position of the number is unknown in some cases then you could extract all the numbers:

```
    Dim str As String = "Seconds 7200 Now"

    Dim num As Integer = CInt(String.Join(String.Empty,
                                          (From c As Char In str
                                          Where Integer.TryParse(c, num))))
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Worked like a charm, with a little modification, You mentioned the CInt, I'll try to research on how to use those.

Comment: @LeoElvinLee If you think you dont need CInt/Convert.ToInt32, then you need to turn Option Strict On